# The vpn connection fails becuase the vpn service failed to start

Tags: vpn, pptpd

I have a problem in add pptp vpn.

I just upgrade ubuntu by `sudo apt-get upgrade` and the VPN PPTP stop working with the message:

```
The VPN Connection 'VPN Connection 1' failed because the VPN service failed to start
```

Comment: Have you rebooted yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
apt-get install network-manager-pptp
apt-get install network-manager-pptp-gnome
apt-get install network-manager-strongswan
apt-get install network-manager-vpnc
apt-get install network-manager-vpnc-gnome
/etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```